# circleci: How to run a job with multiple contexts for each environments

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci-2.0

I'm using circleCI to deploy production or staging environments.
I want to use same job with contexts for each branches corresponding to each environment, because I don't like to write same code for each environments.

I want to write like below.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: google/cloud-sdk
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: <deploying commands>

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          context: production

      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - develop
          context: staging
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a better option for don't create multiple workflows which can cause complexity specifically in case your workflow run multiple jobs, some triggered only for specific branches, others don't.

YAML is a data serialization language so you can still use its features to simplify the declaration.

According to your example, we might have something like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy: &deploy
    docker:
      - image: google/cloud-sdk
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: <deploying commands>
  deploy-production:
    <<: *deploy
  deploy-staging:
    <<: *deploy

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy-production:
    jobs:
      - deploy-production:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          context: production
      - deploy-staging:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - develop
          context: staging
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this like below with using multiple workflows.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: google/cloud-sdk
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: <deploying commands>

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy-production:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
          context: production

  deploy-staging:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - develop
          context: staging
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use multiple contexts in a workflow

https://circleci.canny.io/cloud-feature-requests/p/multiple-contexts-in-a-workflow

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/#combining-contexts

```
context:
  - context-a
  - context-b
```